# Leak of memory and optimization

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bitmap

I'm currently developing an Android application and I can't end it because of few issue as "Out of Memory", I think there is two part in my code which could cause leak.

- First : The application has to play like 12 tones at the same time (10 different frequencies). I found a piece of code on Stack Overflow which allow me to play a list of frequencies at the same time : (I think this is cause by AudioTrack but I don't know how to solve it)

  ```
  public static void runList(final List<Double> freq) {

  if(audioTrack!=null){
      audioTrack.release();
      audioTrack=null;
  }

  final List<AudioTrack> audioTrackList = new ArrayList();
  final AudioTrack audioTrack0;
  final AudioTrack audioTrack1;


      genTone(freq.get(0));                       
      audioTrack0 = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
              (int) sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_DEFAULT,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
              generatedSnd.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

      audioTrack0.play();
      audioTrack0.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

      genTone(freq.get(1));                       
      audioTrack1 = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
              (int) sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_DEFAULT,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
              generatedSnd.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

      audioTrack1.play();
      audioTrack1.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              //compteur : not more than 2 AudioTrack
              audioTrack0.release();
              audioTrack1.release();
          }

      }, 1000);
    }
  ```

(With this I can only play 2 tones at the same time)

- Then : In the same activity the application has to display on the screen 10 image View, each one is moving with a different way. All these image View have been previously decoded from Bitmap. I think that the leak come from here. I've tried to release Bitmap after using it, but nothing to do, I can only display like 3 or 4 image moving on the screen before a crash (Out of Memory). There is maybe a better and lighter way to anim image, for example, to animate an image and make it follow a triangle way, I use this :

  ```
  private void triangleAnim(final ImageView patternImage, final int bpm, final int i, final double frequency) {

  resetN();
  int randomLeft = (int)(Math.random() * (maxRandomLeft-minRandomLeft)) + minRandomLeft;
  int randomTop = (int)(Math.random() * (maxRandomTop-minRandomTop)) + minRandomTop;

  final Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(randomLeft, randomLeft + 300,randomTop,randomTop + 300 ); 
  anim.setDuration(60000/bpm);
  final Animation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(randomLeft +300, randomLeft-300, randomTop+300, randomTop+300 );
  anim2.setDuration(60000/bpm);
  final Animation anim3 = new TranslateAnimation(randomLeft-300, randomLeft, randomTop+300, randomTop );
  anim3.setDuration(60000/bpm);
  su = new SoundUtils();
  su.setDuration(60000/bpm);
  patternImage.startAnimation(anim);

  anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
          patternImage.startAnimation(anim2);
          ;
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
  });

  anim2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
          patternImage.startAnimation(anim3);
          ;
          incrementN();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {    
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
      }
  });

  anim3.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {                           
          if(n <= i){
              patternImage.startAnimation(anim);

          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
  });  }
  ```
- Finally, is there any software or code or anything else that could help me to find where my application has leak of memory ? I can link you errors from LogCat if needed.

Sorry for my english, hope there is not much mistakes.

UPDATE :

Here is my logcat :

```
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at      android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:903)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:880)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:847)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.AllocateCache(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:451)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.initializeCamera(JavaCameraView.java:184)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.connectCamera(JavaCameraView.java:239)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.onEnterStartedState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:355)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.processEnterState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:318)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.checkCurrentState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:311)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.enableView(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:228)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at ui.fragment.TakePictureFragment$1.onManagerConnected(TakePictureFragment.java:71)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1119)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1136)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-31 17:54:03.931: E/AndroidRuntime(15181):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To decode Bitmaps I use this :

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);              
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale++;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;

}
```

Comment: put your logcat where it is saying it has leaked memory

Comment: 10 bitmaps, that is alooooot of memory, how u decoded it? Post ur code and tag me back thanks.

Comment: Here is the logcat OutofMemory causes by imageview

Comment: Can you log the scale and see what is the number that always return? And since you only need a bitmap with fixed size i guess you dont need to loop through scaling it. Just give a fixed inSampleSize = 4, or above. Or just use scaleBitmap but that will reduce the quality but i assume it wont be that obvious since the image size is gonna be so small.

Answer (score 0):

Just one quick thought: Make sure to close your InputStream(s), `BitmapFactory.decodeStream();` doesn't seem to do this in the source code